# Paw Patrol characters (dogs) - german names

Tags: translation

The following characters (especially dogs) exist in the tv series of [Paw Patrol](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAW_Patrol):

```
Ryder 
Chase 
Marshall 
Skye 
Rocky 
Rubble
Zuma
```

There are some more but let's stick with those.
What are possible german names that you could use to replace them? For example "Rocky" - "Steini".

[image]

Comment: You might get better results by asking a German-speaking 6-year-old! :-)

Comment: I do not understand the question. By "What are possible german names", do you mean other names than the names that those characters have [in the actual German dubbing of the show](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAW_Patrol#Hauptfiguren_%E2%80%93_die_PAW_Patrol/Mighty_Pups)? If so, this question seems highly opinion-based to me. If it's about the names actually used in the German version, on the other hand, the question should IMHO be closed as answerable by publicly accessible reference works.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: Though I did give a (partial) answer, I have to agree that this is a closable question. It's more posing a topic for discussion than actually asking for information. It's also a translation request, which are considered off- topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great deal of wordplay in the names, and wordplay is usually difficult to translate into other languages. For example "Zuma" is clearly meant to be a play on "zoomer". So I might go with *Rasa*, which sounds similar to *Raser* -- "racer/speeder". Another option might be *Jäger* seeing as hunting is associated with dogs and *jagen* can also be to run quickly. In my experience though, proper names are usually not translated, and this seems to be the case here according to the German Wikipedia article linked to in the comments. It might be an interesting exercise to come up with creative German-sounding names here, but seeing as there is no "correct" answer, I'm not sure that it's possible to help much with it here.

A similar, but more serious translation problem is posed by made-up common nouns, the kind you might see in science fiction and video games. Common nouns are usually translated, even if they were just made up in the original. An example is "Battlestar Galactica" which in German is *Kampfstern Galactica*. German has a great capacity to make meaningful compounds and neologisms from simpler words and affixes, so finding German equivalents for made-up words in English should not be a big problem.